# What is the meaning of the word "pod" here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of the word "pod" here?

> This is a good tactic to balance out a particular salesly email. So,
>   if you've linked to a product page with one email pod, why not feature
>   a YouTube video in another.

https://econsultancy.com/blog/67214-email-marketing-finding-the-perfect-blend-of-content-product

The free dictionary made put the idea in my head that perhaps the author uses it on the analogy with peas or beans pod. But I want to be sure.
http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pod

Comment: The term "pod" is used a dozen different ways in computerese.  I have no idea what sense is intended above -- you'd have to be familiar with the specific technologies involved to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the key is the word *linked*:

> So if you've **linked** to a product page with one email pod ....

The article you've cited talks about what url's to put in sales emails to consumers.  These links can be fashioned so that the target web page can determine that it was reached via the email.  Thus they're known as "**p**roof **o**f **d**elivery" link**s** or **pods** because clicking the link confirms that the recipient got the email.